# Discussion about my thesis

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I'm one step closer for completing my thesis but I have a question for you 'cause I don't know if the way I'm doing it is right.
First of all. I wanted to make a program that runs in the background and sends a message to someone with the user's location when a new sms is received.
I have a programm that has 3 different layouts. When the user opens the programm for the first time, a service is created that checks for new messages. The service also has a locationlistener that checks regularly for user's location and save the longitude and the latitude in two variables. Although, the gps needs around 1 minute to find my location, in the end, it does. I don't know why it takes so long to find the location. So that's my first of the problems. A Broadcast Receiver is analysing the new sms and keeps the cellphone number. It creates a sms that has a link to Google Maps with the longitude and latitude of the user.
One of the three layouts, is the "Settings" of the program that saves the user's preferences using SharedPreferences and PreferenceManager.
The second layout is about sending the user's location manually and not automatically from the Service... I couldn't find a proper way to pass the values of the longitude and latitude from the service to the activity of the second layout so I made the service to save longitude and latitude using SharedPreferences.... That's my second problem 'cause I think that this is kind of wrong. The Activity sends the user's location with a sms when a button is being pushed.
Now the third and final layout is about a map. There is a button in the third layout that saves the current location as user's home using the SharedPreferences. Inside the onMapReady I have put the buttons OnClickListener so, when the map is ready, and the button is pressed, it will create a marker in the map that shows the user's home. The user's location is taken (as in the Activity of the second layout) with the SharedPreferences method. Which I don't know if is a correct way to use....
So am asking you guys, is it cool to use SharedPreferences that way?? Would be better if I save the longitude and latitude in a file??
Please any help or opinion will be appreciated...

Comment: If you could structure your question in ordered steps, it would make it easier to assess.

Comment: This kind of questions are not meant for this site. I'm also a student and in every university there are professors which have their time when you can ask questions especially when you are writing your final thesis. You have to ask this question to your mentor and his assistants and then come with the code which does not work and stackoverflow will try to help you.

Comment: Will I get a degree for answering it?)

Comment: @eugensunic ok thank you my friend. I should do this.

Comment: @Onik No, but you will help me getting one ^_^

Comment: _"Would be better if I save the longitude and latitude in a file??"_... `SharedPreferences` is also a file, probably DB per se (internally). If so, it's even faster to read/write data from...